# Cannot login to SQL Server 2008 remotely - Error 1326 - Incorrect user or pass

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, remote-access, remote-server

I have a problem trying to connect to SQL Server 2008 SP3. It's really strange, I have looked everywhere for an answer and couldn't find anyone experiencing the same problems. I'll try to explain.

I can connect to my server locally, both using Windows login and SQL Server authentication, but when I try to connect remotely, I get error 1326 and an error message specifying `Incorrect username or password`.

Then I login locally to SQL, but the error log doesn't show up anything.

Yesterday, it showed the login errors, but now it's not showing up anymore. It's like it's trying to connect to another instance of SQL, though I checked by doing `SELECT @@VERSION` and running `osql -L` from the command line, and both of them show just one server instance running.

What's even more strange, I just tried stopping the SQL Server service and logging in again. It still shows the same error: 1326 - Incorrect username or password. It should have told me that the server cannot be found or something like that. How does it show incorrect user or pass when the server is offline?

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Try using an IP address.

Comment: Does the server have `Allow remote connections to this server` enabled?